# hg unbundle failure: journal:dirstate journal.branch store/journal

Tags: mercurial, bundle

I've been tasked with rehosting some repositories that were on repositoryhosting.com  Some of these repositories are in mercurial with which I am unfamiliar.  I am following [these instructions](http://repositoryhosting.com/support/faq/export_data) To unbundle the repository on my new machine, but have been unsuccessful.  Repeated attempts have been unfruitful, yeilding messages as follows:

```
myhost:repo/path$ hg unbundle path/to/bundle
abort:Operation not permitted: /path/to/my/repo/.hg/journal.dirstate

myhost:repo/path$ hg unbundle path/to/bundle
abort:Operation not permitted: /path/to/my/repo/.hg/journal.branch

myhost:repo/path$ hg unbundle path/to/bundle
abort:Operation not permitted: /path/to/my/repo/.hg/store/journal
```

`hg help unbundle` has not been helpful.  I suppose the answer is probably simple, but not sure where to look.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `hg clone <bundle-file> <dest>`.